# pass result values of MultipartFormData.FilePart

Tags: scala, playframework

i'm scala/play beginner studying for three months.
now implement file uploading then insert result values of MultipartFormData.FilePart as tags into mysql.

the problem is following part;

(FileUploadController.scala)

```
  def upload = silhouette.SecuredAction.async(parse.multipartFormData(handleFilePartAsFile)) { implicit request =>

    val fileOption = request.body.file("picName").map {

      case FilePart(key, filename, contentType, file) =>
        logger.info(s"key = ${key}, filename = ${filename}, contentType = ${contentType}, file = $file")

        val data = operateOnTempFile(file)

    FileUploadFormSupport.picsave(FilePart(key, filename, contentType, file))
   
        data
  
    }
```

(FileUploadFormSupport.scala)

```
  def picsave() :Unit = {

//sql
 
}
```

> def picsave() :Unit = {

in other cases ,for example case class Data in models/User.scala, i wrote following line;

> def insert(data:Data) :Unit =

i should pass appropriate result values and types but when wrote following line;

> def picsave(FilePart(key, filename, contentType, file)): Unit =

then compile errror;

> ')' expected but '(' found.

occured.

other attemps;

> def picsave(FilePart(key, filename, contentType, file)): Unit =
>
> def picsave(FilePart(key:String, filename:String, contentType:String, file)): Unit =
>
> def picsave(key:String, filename:String, contentType:String, file:A) : Unit =

are also not good.

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.8/api/java/play/mvc/Http.MultipartFormData.FilePart.html

Comment: An obvious issue is your method definition `def picsave(FilePart(key, filename, contentType, file)): Unit`, it should be like `def picsave(part: FilePart): Unit`.

Comment: thanks for your comment, Alex.